# Ensure pip error when creating a virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

When I run `python -m venv virtual` I get the following error:

```
Error: Command '['/Users/stephenlang/Projects/Python_Projects/Intermediate Projects/Personal-Website/virtual/bin/python', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Nevertheless I still get a folder called virtual which gets created.  The only thing is that in the virtual/bin folder there is no pip.

Why is this error occurring and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is your OS and what does `python -V` show?

Comment: Mac Mojave 10.14.6
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)